# Material-UI adds padding to the body tag when a dialog is opened

Tags: reactjs, dialog, material-ui

I am using Material-UI in my react application. Recently, I updated my packages to the latest version. Now, when I open a dialog in my application, `padding-right: 17px;` will be added to the body tag.
I also checked the Material-UI site, and this is happening on their website too with dialogs.

Is this a bug with the new version of Material-UI?

How can I remove this padding from the body tag when opening a dialog?

**Update:** This padding will be added to the body tag with Drawer, Menu, Dialog, and Popover components.

Answer (score 17):

as it was mentioned by @Reins you can use `disableScrollLock` property. The thing is sometimes this property is nested on components's input so you need to use `inputProps` in order to set it. Here is an example with Select component:

```
<Select
    className={classes.select}
    inputProps={{MenuProps: {disableScrollLock: true}}}
    ...
/>
```

Sometimes you may want to dig into MUI codebase in order to figure out how to apply some nested element's properties.

Answer (score 12):

Just give `disableScrollLock={ true }`.
I think it will solve the issue because I had the same.

Answer (score 9):

I added `disableScrollLock` prop to my Dialog Component.
It worked.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a mui-fixed class for handling this issue, it's helpful for me.

Here is a link for material UI mui-fixed document :
https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#why-do-the-fixed-positioned-elements-move-when-a-modal-is-opened

Hope this will help anyone.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How to use this class to fix the problem? I mean, this class should be assigned to which tag or component?

Comment: If I assign the `mui-fixed` class to the main div tag that I have, the padding will be doubled.

Comment: You need to add this class to the main div of your component.

Comment: It didn't work. The documentation said that this class is for preventing the movement of elements when the scrollbar is removed by modal. 
But, I don't have a scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to add

```
overflow: auto;
```

to the #root selector:

```
#root { 
    ... other css that was there before
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I add in my main css file the following snippet of code and I get rid of body margins:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized this came from a parent Container. I just added this and it worked for me. Also realized this is adaptive to screen size, so this code is applied to all the sizes from xs and up breakpoints.

```
 sx={{
      [theme.breakpoints.up("xs")]: {
        padding: 0
      },
    }}
```