# Click on MUI Select dropdown padding automatically add to the body

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I faced an issue when I click on MUI Select dropdown the padding automatically add to the body. I add `disableScrollLock={ true }` in the Menuprop the I add menu prop to Select tag but still faced the issue...Please, Provide me better solution

I implement a MUI Multi Select dropdown when I Click on Select Dropdown padding automatically add in the body

Here is the code...

```
import * as React from 'react';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import InputAdornment from '@mui/material/InputAdornment';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import SearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Search";
import KeyboardArrowDownIcon from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowDown';
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 50;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    sx: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width:220,
      fontSize:'2rem'
    } 
  },
};

const classes = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    width: 300
  },
  indeterminateColor: {
    color: "#f50057"
  },
  selectAllText: {
    fontWeight: 500
  },
  selectedAll: {
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)"
    }
  }
}));

const names = [
  'Oliver Hansen',
  'Van Henry',
  'April Tucker',
  'Ralph Hubbard',
  'Omar Alexander',
  'Carlos Abbott',
  'Miriam Wagner',
  'Bradley Wilkerson',
  'Virginia Andrews',
  'Kelly Snyder',
];
// const containsText = (text, searchText) =>
//   text.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) > -1;

export default function MultipleSelectCheckmarks({id,sendDataToParentCity,sendDataToParentBrand,sendDataToParentSKUs}) {

  const [searchText, setSearchText]    = React.useState("");
  const [personName, setPersonName]    = React.useState([]);
  const [optionLength,setOptionLength] = React.useState();
  const isAllSelected = names.length > 0 && personName.length === names.length;

  const displayedOptions = names.filter((option) =>option.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) > -1)
  


  const handleChange = (event) => {
   
    const value = event.target.value;
    if (value[value.length - 1] === "all") {
      setPersonName(personName.length === names.length ? [] : names);
      return;
    }
    if(!value.includes(undefined))
        setPersonName(value); 

    setOptionLength(value.join(',').split(',').length-1)    
        
    if(id==1)
        sendDataToParentCity(value)
    else if(id==2)       
        sendDataToParentBrand(value) 
    else if(id==3)
        sendDataToParentSKUs(value)

    };

  const serachSet = (event)=>{
    setSearchText(event.target.value)
  }


  // selected.join(',').split(',').length +" "+ "Selected"
  // + " & " +selected.join(',').split(',').length-1+
  "Others"
  return (
    <div>
        <Select
        
        defaultValue = {'Select Brand'}
        autoWidth={true}
        style={{width: "13.4rem",height: "2.3rem",background: "white"}}
          id="search-select"
          sx={{
            '& #search-select': {
                fontSize: '13px',
             }
           }}
          multiple
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          renderValue={(selected) =>selected.join(',').split(',').length===names.length ? "All Selected" : selected.join(',').split(',').length==1 ? selected.join(',').split(',')[0] :(selected.join(',').split(',')[0]+" & "+optionLength)  +" Others!"}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
          onClose={() => setSearchText("")}
          IconComponent = {KeyboardArrowDownIcon}
          withAll={true}
        >
            <MenuItem  onKeyDown={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
            <TextField 
              size="small"
              placeholder="Search"
              sx={{fontSize: '2rem'}}
              fullWidth
              InputProps={{
                startAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position="start" >
                    <SearchIcon />
                  </InputAdornment>
                )
              }}
              onChange={serachSet}
            />
          </MenuItem>
          
        <MenuItem value="all">
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Checkbox
              checked={isAllSelected}
              indeterminate={
                personName.length > 0 && personName.length < names.length
              }
            />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText
            classes={{ primary: classes.selectAllText }}
            primary="Select All"
          />
        </MenuItem>
        

          {displayedOptions.map((name) => (
            <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
              <Checkbox checked={personName.indexOf(name) > -1} />
              <ListItemText primary={name} />
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi an welcome to SO. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. As of right now your question is very broad and not debuggable. Please add your code. Show us what you've tried and describe exactly what doesn't work for you.

Comment: Did you try to add `disableScrollLock={true}` in `Select` tag like this :-`<Select  disableScrollLock={true}></Select>`

Comment: And also, To better understand the problem you are facing, it would be helpful if you could just include the relevant parts of your code where you are experiencing the issue. If you think it's important to share more of your code, you can use an online code editor. @Muhammad Usama.

Comment: @DSDmark yes Sir, I added disableScrollLock={true} in MenuProps but it's not working for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60682426/material-ui-adds-padding-to-the-body-tag-when-a-dialog-is-opened